SwiftUI aligning a view by percentage
Using SwiftUI, I have a rectangle that takes up a percentage of the device's width, with an inner rectangle in an overlay.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.purple)
            .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical]) { myWidth, axis in
                if axis == .horizontal {
                    return myWidth * 0.8
                } else {
                    return 40.0
                }
            }
            .overlay(CandyView(theWidth: 0.25), alignment: .leading)
            .cornerRadius(8.0)
    }
}

struct CandyView: View {
    var theWidth: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.white)
            .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical]) { myWidth, axis in
                if axis == .horizontal {
                    return myWidth * theWidth
                } else {
                    return 35.0
                }
            }
            .cornerRadius(7.0)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 3.0)
    }
}

This will give me something like this:

I can place the inner rectangle on the other side, or in the middle, by changing the alignment:
.overlay(CandyView(theWidth: 0.25), alignment: .leading)

But what if I wanted to place the inner rectangle 20% along the outer rectangle? Is there an easy way to specify a percentage to place it where I'd like it to be? I'd prefer not to use GeometryReader, but I'm open to suggestions.

You could always change the overlay to an HStack containing a spacer + the marker shape.
You might notice, that the white marker in your example has a width that is 25% of the screen, not 25% of the underlying view. This is because, the reference container for .containerRelativeFrame is actually the screen in this case. See the documentation for more details.
→ To correct the width, the base fraction needs to be applied to all overlay fractions too.
Btw, the .overlay modifier you are using is deprecated, suggest using overlay(alignment:content:) instead. Also, .cornerRadius is deprecated, suggest applying a clip shape instead, or just use a RoundedRectangle as the base shape:
private let baseWidthFraction: CGFloat = 0.8

RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
    .fill(.purple)
    .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical]) { width, axis in
        axis == .horizontal ? width * baseWidthFraction : 40.0
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color.clear
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal) { width, axis in
                    width * 0.2 * baseWidthFraction
                }
            CandyView(theWidth: 0.25 * baseWidthFraction)
        }
    }



An alternative way to split the view is to use a custom Layout. For the case here, there is only one child to position, so the layout implementation can be greatly simplified:
struct FractionalLayout: Layout {
    var spacerFraction: CGFloat = 0.0
    let contentFraction: CGFloat

    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        proposal.replacingUnspecifiedDimensions()
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        if let child = subviews.first {
            let x = bounds.minX + (bounds.width * spacerFraction)
            let w = bounds.width * contentFraction
            child.place(
                at: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.minY),
                proposal: .init(width: w, height: bounds.height)
            )
        }
    }
}

Example use:
.overlay {
    CandyView(spacerWidth: 0.2, theWidth: 0.25)
}

struct CandyView: View {
    var spacerWidth = CGFloat.zero
    let theWidth: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        FractionalLayout(spacerFraction: spacerWidth, contentFraction: theWidth) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
                .fill(.white)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 3)
        .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
    }
}

The result is very similar to the previous result, except that the width of the marker is now determined after allowing for the horizontal padding, which means it is actually slightly more precise than before:


For a more generic Layout implementation that supports multiple subviews, see the answer to SwiftUI How to Set Specific Width Ratios for Child Elements in an HStack (it was my answer). In that implementation, the available width is split according to the weights given to the subviews. Here's how it could be used to give the same result here:
.overlay {
    WeightedHStack {
        Color.clear.layoutWeight(20)
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
            .fill(.white)
            .frame(height: 35)
            .layoutWeight(25)
        Color.clear.layoutWeight(55)
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 3)
}


Oh yea, the custom Layout works really well, more elegant and (yes) precise than the spacer method. And thank you for the deprecations, I hadn't noticed them!

You can play around with alignmentGuides if you really don't want to use GeometryReader.
Offset the leading alignment guide of the purple rectangle by a desired amount to move the CandyView along the purple rectangle.
let widthPercentage = 0.25
let offsetPercentage = 0.2
let padding = 3.0

RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
    .fill(.purple)
    .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 5, span: 4, spacing: 0)
    .frame(height: 40)
    .alignmentGuide(.leading) { dimensions in
        dimensions[.leading] + ((dimensions.width - padding) * (1 - widthPercentage)) * offsetPercentage
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        CandyView(theWidth: widthPercentage)
    }

Note that here I have also taken into account the width of the CandyView, so that when offsetPercentage is 1, the right side of the CandyView will be aligned with the right side of the purple rectangle.
Changing the alignmentGuide of the purple rectangle might affect its own position, if it is itself aligned leading in its parent. If that is the case, you can put the alignmentGuide on an extra layer of overlay, like this:
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
    .fill(.purple)
    .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 5, span: 4, spacing: 0)
    .frame(height: 40)
    .overlay {
        Color.clear
            .alignmentGuide(.leading) { dimensions in
                ...
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                CandyView(theWidth: widthPercentage)
            }
    }

As for the CandyView, using containerRelativeFrame here will not create a frame that is relative to the purple rectangle, because the purple rectangle does not count as a "container".
To fix this, you can again play around with alignmentGuide:
Color.clear
    .frame(height: 35)
    .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
            .fill(.white)
            .alignmentGuide(.trailing) { dimensions in
                dimensions[.trailing] + dimensions.width * (1 - theWidth)
            }
    }
    .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 7))
    .padding(.horizontal, 3)

The white rectangle is moved along the horizontal axis by offsetting the .trailing alignment guide. It always has the same width as the parent view (minus padding), but it will be clipped by another rounded rectangle as it moves around, creating the illusion that its width is changing.

Thank you, this does work. I don't find it as clear to read as the custom Layout (as given by @benzyknees above)
